# Как работает получение элемента по ключу в словаре?

Tags: python, dict

Каким образом работает присваивание нового элемента словарю через `d[new_key]=new_val`? Что возвращается из `d[new_key]` в этом случае? Или как интерпретатор отличает, что мы хотим вставить новый элемент, а не обновить старый таким синтаксисом? Или почему `d[new_key]` вызывает исключение, если не поставить `=`?

Comment: «как интерпретатор отличает» — по знаку `=` и отличает, наверное?

Comment: Вообще, такой синтаксис это синтаксический сахар для вызова магического метода `__setitem__`, то есть для словаря это эквивалентно коду `dict.__setitem__(d, new_key, new_val)` — а дальше метод уже сам как-то проверяет, вставлять или обновлять

Comment: А если не поставить знак `=`, то это будет уже не присваивание, а чтение, которое эквивалентно вызову `dict.__getitem__(d, new_key)` — и тогда уже магический метод `__getitem__` как-то проверяет наличие ключа и кидает KeyError в случае его отсутствия

Comment: @andreymal т.е. ещё при парсинге синтаксиса проверяется наличие `=` после `]`? И `]=` и `]` совершенно разные методы вызывает?

Comment: Я не изучал реализацию парсера, но в [грамматике](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) есть отдельное правило `assignment`, так что скорее всего да

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо за объяснение